# How do I change the image of button on click?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a preset image of a button in a custom cell, and I want that image to change when the button is clicked. How would I do that? I put a switch in the button, and it works. When it is clicked it will play a song, and when it is clicked again it will stop. I just want the image to change. How would I do that? The name of the button is `playbutton`.

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = friendstable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendsMusicCell


    cell.playbutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.customtitle.text = titleofsong[indexPath.row]
    cell.customartist.text = artist[indexPath.row]
    cell.customtitle.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.customtitle.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.customartist.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.customartist.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()

    cell.customtitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()



    return cell
}


func playmusic(sender: UIButton!) {

    let playButtonrow = sender.tag
    print(titleofsong[playButtonrow])
    switch(buttonState){
    case 0:
    let searchTerm: String = titleofsong[playButtonrow]

    let itunesSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

    if let escapedSearchTerm = itunesSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let urlPath = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(escapedSearchTerm)&media=music"
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!


        print("Search iTunes API at URL \(url)")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            do {
                if let dict: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                {


                    let previewUrl = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["previewUrl"] as? String)!)!
                    print(previewUrl)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(URL: previewUrl)
                    self.player.rate = 1.0
                    self.player.play()



                }

            } catch let jsonError as NSError {

                }
            }
        task.resume()

        }
    buttonState = 1;
    break;
    case 1:
        player.pause()

        buttonState = 0;
    default: break

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to refresh the UITableViewCell from your playmusic function to change the state of the Button image

Comment: You are sending UIButton instance to the playmusic function, you can change the properties of the "sender" instance within that function as said by @Nguyen Hoan . Why do you want it declare globally when you can access within playmusic function ?

Comment: How can I access the playbutton through the function?

Comment: Am not into Swift but you can do something like let playButton = sender, in the above playmusic function you are just retrieving tag value (which is row index) and storing in playButtonRow. The "sender" itself is a UIButton instance which you are passing from tableView method.

Comment: then you can do something like playButton.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)   or directly sender.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare playButton globally

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell = friendstable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendsMusicCell


cell.playbutton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.playButton.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
cell.playButton.setImage(pauseImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
cell.playbutton.addTarget(self, action: "playmusic:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

cell.customtitle.text = titleofsong[indexPath.row]
cell.customartist.text = artist[indexPath.row]
cell.customtitle.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
cell.customtitle.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
cell.customartist.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
cell.customartist.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()

cell.customtitle.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()



return cell
}
```

in your playmusic function you can add the following line at the beginning

```
sender.selected = !sender.selected
```

Answer (score 0):

It 's so easy. You can set image for uibutton with UIControlState
ex:

```
self.btnPlay.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.btnPlay.setImage(pauseImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

And When you click it, you change state of btnPlay:

```
self.btnPlay.selected = !self.btnPlay.selected
```

Comment: Should I instantiate btnPlay globally?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do this since I can only access `playbutton` in the tableView function, and I want to change the image of  `playbutton` in the playmusic function, and I cannot access playbutton in the function.

Comment: you can setimage in  cellForRowAtIndexPath .And in playmusic function  set selected for playbutton, it 's sender